# Retrieving the first element from data snapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, snapshot

I'm trying to pull out the first record from the code below.

```
exports.sendBuyerNotification = functions.database.ref('/Bids/{uid}').onWrite((async(change,context)=>{

 const bid= change.after.val();
 const prodid = bid.prodID;
 const new_price = bid.price;
 const biddata= admin.database().ref('/Bids');
 biddata.orderByChild('prodID').equalTo(prodid).limitToLast(2).once('value',function(snapshot){
    var old_data = [];
    old_data.push(snapshot.val());
    var mystring = JSON.parse(snapshot.val())
    return console.log("Old price" + mystring[0].price);
```

Result : undefined

Comment: Check if your prodID exists in the database, then try doing `console.log(snapshot.val())` and see what value you are getting. I suspect it will be an array ... which means you can do: `const mystring = snapshot.val()`

Comment: Edit your question to include a sample of the JSON at `Bids` (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). Also update the Result to indicate what you'd expect given the JSON in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you probably will get back an array of up to 2 items from the database because of `limitToLast(2)`. But you need to check if you're actually getting data back from the database before anything else - see the `console.log` statements below - I have made some other suggestions also.

Try this and see if it solves you issue:

```js
exports.sendBuyerNotification = functions.database.ref('/Bids/{uid}').onWrite((async(change,context) => {

 const bid = change.after.val();
 console.log(bid) // are you getting a value from this?
 const prodid = bid.prodID;
 const new_price = bid.price;
 const biddata= admin.database().ref('/Bids');
 biddata.orderByChild('prodID')
            .equalTo(prodid)
            .limitToLast(2)
            .once('value', function(snapshot){  
                console.log(snapshot.val()) // check you are getting a value?

                const myString = snapshot.val();
                console.log("Old price" + myString[0].price);

                return {
                        message: "Old price $" + myString[0].price,
                        values: snapshot.val()
                }; 
            })
})
```